# Ideas on how to securely record how long it takes a user to answer a quiz challenge?

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz web application, players of the quiz are given 20 seconds to answer each question and are rewarded with time bonuses for answering faster.

What are some ways I could record the amount of time it takes the user to answer the question that would be difficult/impossible to manipulate?

There may be prizes awarded to the players with the highest scores, so there would be incentive to manipulate the post data.

This is the only idea I've had so far, but it seems easily to manipulate to me:

1. Questions will load in via AJAX.
2. Store the time (in milliseconds) that the player receives the question via JavaScript.
3. Assign a hash for each question and a hash for each individual answer.
4. When the player selects an answer, create a new hash that contains the hash of the question  + hash of the answer + hash of the total time difference in milliseconds.
5. POST that hash to my server.
6. Server side I would have a cached index of all possible valid hashes for the correct answer + time combination for that question. (20,000 total hashes for each question. One for each millisecond, up to 20 seconds)
7. If the submitted hash matches one in the index, the player gets the correct answer and their time bonus.

I've also considered using an encrypted Flash file just to crunch the hash that's going to be submitted, but unless I'm mistaken it's pretty easy to use a decompiler on those to see what's going on. So it doesn't provide much more security.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Edit - I had been thinking about this so much that I completely forgot about users being able to change their clock, which nullified any chance of securely doing this client side.

So server side timestamps are really the only reliable way to go.

Comment: Javascript cannot be used to securely do *anything*. You should be using a server-side solution to measure time.

Comment: @arxanas, except, of course, server-side javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: don't trust anything the client says, and don't do anything on the client if at all possible.

Use server-side recording for this. e.g.

1. set session variable recording time when the "gimme the question text" request comes in
2. set session varaible recording time when the answer comes in

boom. The only way the user can affect this is by asking for the question text, and by sending in the answer. Changing their system clock, fudging with the data in the browser, fudging with the data in the HTTP request as it hits the wire - all useless.

Comment: This is definitely a good simple approach. The only reason I thought of doing it client side was in order to compensate for delay, but maybe it would make sense to just give everyone a 200ms delay factored in to their time.

Since the data sent via each request is incredibly small, it shouldn't take anyone very long to download the entire request.

What do you think about that approach?

Comment: Unless your users are on an RFC 1149-compliant link, latency is usually not all that horrible these days: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt

Comment: Ha. Ok you've convinced me. Accepting your answer. Thank you, Marc and everyone else in here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you could set a `$_SESSION['receivedQuestion'] = time();` when the user receives the question, and when the user answers it you check for `time()-$_SESSION['receivedQuestion'] <= 20`. Note that this could give a bit of trouble when the user's internet connection is slow, but this shouldn't be too big of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a server-side timestamp when the question is asked, and another when it's answered correctly?

I understand delay in requests could cause issue, but leaving it to the client isn't very secure.